# Prove $B = (A∪B)−(A −B)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How to prove $B = (A∪B)−(A −B)$ in terms of set theory ?

I can prove by using diagram, but how Demorgan's Law is applicable here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since in general $X -Y=X \cap Y ^C$, you get:

$$(A \cup B) - (A -B)= (A \cup B) \cap (A -B)^C$$

$$ =(A \cup B) \cap (A \cap B^C)^C \text{ (and now we do DeMorgan!)}$$

$$=(A \cup B) \cap (A^C \cup B) \text{ (now we do reverse Distribution)}$$

$$=(A \cap A^C)\cup B = \emptyset \cup B =B$$

Comment: That's Perfect !!

Comment: @JonGarrick You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 3):

$x\in (A\cup B)-(A-B)$ iff

$x\in (A\cup B) \wedge x\notin(A-B)$ iff

$(x\in A \vee x\in B)\wedge (x\notin A\ \vee x\in B)$ iff

$(x\in A \wedge x\notin A) \vee x\in B$.

The first assertion cannot happen so $x\in B$.

Answer (score 0):

In natural language, the expression on the right is

> > the set of all things that are in $A$ or in $B$, but [and] are *not* among the things that are in $A$ but not in $B$.

A little thought shows that this is just a long-winded way of saying "$B$".
@edgar.alonso's answer proves it formally.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:
$$(A\cup B)-(A-B)=((A-B)\cup (A\cap B)\cup (B-A))-(A-B)=(A\cap B)\cup (B-A)=B.$$